# Off loading collision detection (and other processor intensive loops) to a WebWorker in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I've been playing about with web workers recently and I managed to off load A* path finding to a worker thread using the following technique...

1. Push a reference to an object onto an array when the object posts a message to the worker
2. Shift the next item from the array when the worker posts back

My game has a feature where creatures respond to noises in the environment. Ideally what I want to achieve is...

1. Something in the game makes a noise with a radius
2. Pass the origin of the noise and the list of creatures to the web worker
3. The web worker responds with a list of creatures that are in range of the noise

Obviously there's an issue because I can't pass an array of objects to the worker and I'm struggling to think of a way around this.

**Updated question:** 
How do I (efficiently) tell the main thread that creature X and creature Y heard a sound?

Any suggestions?

---

**can you give an example of what you are trying to post to the web worker, for example console log it right before offloading it**

Something like this...

```
var iNoiseRadius = 100;
var aCreatures = [
    {id: 1, x: 0, y: 0},
    {id: 2, x: 200, y: 0},
    {id: 3, x: 100, y: 100},
    {id: 4, x: 50, y: 400},
    {id: 5, x: 100, y: 0}
];

....

oWorker.postMessage({
    type: 'noise',
    originator: aCreatures[2],
    radius: iNoiseRadius,
    creatures: aCreatures
});
```

The array of creatures may change in the time between posting the message and receiving the response so the array index is useless.

Comment: can you give an example of what you are trying to post to the web worker, for example console log it right before offloading it?

Comment: does it give some error message?

Comment: just a thought, but the json spec requires the keys (or names) of the json object to be surrounded by quotes, that might be the problem

Comment: No error messages. I'm just stuck on how to return WHICH creatures could hear the noise from the web worker. How can I tell the main thread which creatures need to respond? Do I simply return an array of IDs and look through the creatures array to match them up? This seems a bit inefficient. (PS I would usually quote me keys but I knocked that code up in a few seconds in notepad)

Comment: So the problem isn't posting the array of creatures TO the worker but getting the array of cratures posted FROM the worker TO the main application?

Comment: Correct! How do I (efficiently) tell the main thread that creature X and creature Y heard a sound?

Comment: Does the array of ids cause performance issues with your application? Because it is quite frankly the obvious solution.

Comment: I haven't implemented this yet so I don't know about performance.  I guess that is the obvious solution but it seems so inelegant.  If you post an answer ill accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to tell the main thread that creatures X and Y heard a sound as efficiently as possible.

Logical answer is to return a list of creature ids that were within the radius. This way you'll have to loop through the list again in the main thread.

You could also use the worker's `postMessage` to post the id of each creature within the radius as it is discovered. Pseudocode:

```
// In the WebWorker
forEach(creature in creatures) {
  if (creature is within radius distance of originator) {
    postMessage(creature.id);
  }
}

// In the Main Thread
noiseDetectionWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  notificyCreatureOfNoise(event.data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it serialized JSON. It's not the prettiest solution, but might the be best until WebWorkers are properly implemented (as I understand it the specification allows for any object to be passed in and out of them)

Comment: FWIW, ran into this library today, might be useful in abstracting the whole WebWorker thing: http://adambom.github.com/parallel.js/